# "Oyoyoy" a hefsek?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, song-poetry, chazzan-prayer-leader, hefsek-interruption

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Humming during shmoneh esre](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14931/humming-during-shmoneh-esre)

Is saying "oyoyoy" in places where you're not allowed to speak (e.g. Shemoneh Esreh) a hefsek (interruption)? Does it make a difference that it doesn't have any consonant sounds (in which case "oyoyoy" would be permitted and "aididididi" forbidden)?

Related: [Hefsek (interruption) between the blessing on food and eating the food](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11732/hefsek-interruption-between-the-blessing-on-food-and-eating-the-food), but there the problem is that you distract your mind from the bread (MB 166:1) while here you aren't allowed to talk even if you don't distract your mind.

Comment: duplicate? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14931/759