# Saying "thank you" before taking a bite

Tags: halacha, food, hefsek-interruption, derech-eretz-manners, hamotzi-beracha

The halacha as codified by Shulchan Aruch O.C. 167:6 is that if one interrupts between making Hamotzi and eating the bread, as long as the interruption is related to the meal (not just to eating the bread - see Beis Yosef 167:6 and Magen Avraham) it does not require the person to repeat their blessing.

If one of the people listening to Hamotzi, who has the same rules of interruption according to the Shulchan Aruch, says "thank you" when they are given their slice of bread before they take a bite, does this constitute an unrelated interruption, or can this display of manners be considered related to the meal?

Examples of what is related to the meal, as given by the Beis Yosef, are such things as saying to pass around the food (not just the bread) and telling someone to feed the animals.

Comment: same time-period http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11732/759

Comment: Note this may be one of those cases where if it's permitted it becomes obligatory.

Comment: @DoubleAA It may also be a case where it's forbidden *l'chatchila* but is not considered a *hefseik* after the fact.

Comment: We try to minimize talking as much as possible, many people have the minhag not to speak at all even if it's about the meal

Comment: @Yez Do you mean the Rema 167:6? If not, could you please link to your Beit Yosef?

Comment: @Yez I thought the leniency on this only (with the exception of the rema i cited above) applied to talking between washing and HaMotzi.

Comment: @Yez According to here https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/61027/when-to-say-brocha-when-making-a-lchaim , one is not mafsik for a l'chaim - although I think that's technically not related to the meal (based on the fact that hagafens during the meal are covered by the bracha on the kiddush wine, not by the bracha on motzi like other drinks)

Answer (score 2):

I think the Magen Avraham understands that one is permitted to make a interruption to facilitate the beginning of the meal. So just like the leader can't start eating until he has clarified if his animals have eaten yet and the lack of that knowledge prevents him from starting to eat, so to the Magen Avram allows you to request that food be served to a person (even if he is not eating bread) since that person can not start eating until he has food.

Saying please and thank you is an expression of gratitude/hakarat hatov. However lack of expressing that does not prevent one from eating since the same could be accomplished by saying thank you after the first bite and neither is there a halacha that says "you are forbidden to eat until you say thanks to the one who passed you the food" So even according to the Magen Avram it would be forbidden.

However the Mishne Brurah learns (based on the Bach**) that the case the Mechaber is talking about is where everyone has washed and the request being made is to pass *bread* to someone who wants to make his *own* bracha and not a request to pass him food so he can start eating.** If this is the intent of the Mechaber then there seems to be no reason to think that based on this one would be allowed to say thank you.

** IMHO It could be that the Mishna Brurah also felt that the Magen Avram's p'sak was unclear and therefore chose to learn like the Bach

Source

SA OC 167:6 MB 39

Answer (score 0):

It would seem to be that the example of the mechaber is only in regards to thing that facilitate the eating of the food, IE. One cannot eat before he feeds his animals or to pass the food (Mesechtas Berochos 40a. The Gemorah in Mesechtas Gittin 62 says it is forbidden to “taste.”) Although you point out correctly that an interruption which is not specific to the eating of the bread is not problematic, nevertheless it should only be in regards to the eating of the food in general. Therefore, according to this logic, thank you ;which although is a well mannered thing to do, is only a nicety and not considered inherently a facilitatory action vis-a- vis the food.

Comment: I don't follow your logic...

Comment: @DoubleAA please elaborate

Comment: You say "in regards to the eating of the food in general" and "not specific to the eating of the bread" are ok, but then if it is "not considered inherently a facilitatory action vis-a- vis the food" then it's not ok. Non-sequitur? Where is the logic?

Comment: @DoubleAA the only things which are not considered a hefsek are things which facilitate the eating of the food, IE. passing the food, or feeding animals before eating. both are not considered a halachic seperation between the bracha and the eating. saying thank you has nothing inherently to do with food.

Comment: How do you move from "the eating of the food in general" to "things which facilitate the eating of the food"?

Comment: @DoubleAA it could be my phraseology is mistaken, but my point is that the it is not considered under discussion of whether it is considered a hefsek if it has nothing to do with food in general.

Comment: Why do you assume saying thank you has nothing to do with food in general? Seems to me that it does.

Comment: what does thank you have inherently to food? someonoe opens the door for me i say thank you, someone buys me a present i say thank you. its just a nicety

Comment: Someone buys you flowers and you ask to pass them. That doesn't mean that in the context of food passing doesn't have to do with food. So too here. You are saying thank you _for the food_.

Comment: yes but passing the food is clearly an action which directly facilitates the eating of the food.

Comment: Yes... I thought we were discussing "the eating of the food in general". You never told me "How do you move from 'the eating of the food in general' to 'things which facilitate the eating of the food'?"