# Why does a hefsek make a person not yotzei?

Tags: halacha-theory, hefsek-interruption

There are situations where my fulfillment of an obligation depends on there being no **interruption** between the bracha and the action it covers (like between [washing](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9855/can-i-wash-and-say-please-pass-the-salt/9860#9860) and making motzi) and there are situations where my fulfillment requires that there be no interruption of the one performing the action and my listening (though that is a clunky wording), like the reading/hearing of the megillah.

*But why would an interruption change the mindset* (his [kavannah](http://www.jewishtreats.org/2012/10/being-yotzei.html) to make me yotzei and my kavannah to be made yotzei)? If I sneeze, is that an interruption which should make me not exempted? Is my saying [baruch](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/m/halacha.aspx?id=1112) hu uvaruch shemo (which is a manifestation of my focus on the words of the bracha) a heisach hada'at if I still hear everything and am listening to the words? Is making noise when the koreh says "Haman" any more or less of an interruption if I still hear all the words?

Comment: To be clear, you're asking only about cases in which one person is _motzi_ another, right?

Comment: Yes, but I was also citing a case where one is motzi himself but talking is not necessarily an interruption.